# Call findViewById() for a specific layout? NullPointerException on findViewById()

Tags: java, android

I have an Second class that call a method from the Main class, this method will set a `TextView` with a number, however the app crashes because of a `nullPointerException` for `findViewById()`. I believe the issue is that when `findViewById` is called from another class, it will look for the view in the `setContentView()` of calling class.

So how can a specify which layout `findViewById()` is looking through?
Why is there a 'nullPointerException' ?

```
*************************************************
                  MAIN CLASS
*************************************************

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (!NUMBER.exists()) {
        new File("/data/data/com.app.clicker/files").mkdir();
        writeInt(NUMBER, total = 0);
        writeInt(CLICK, perClick = 1);
        writeInt(CASH, $ = 500);
        setView(R.id.numberView, "", readInt(NUMBER));
        setView(R.id.perClickView, "Per Click ", readInt(CLICK));
        setView(R.id.cash, "Cash ", readInt(CASH));
    } else {
        setView(R.id.perClickView, "Per Click ", readInt(CLICK));
        setView(R.id.cash, "Cash ", readInt(CASH));
        setView(R.id.numberView, "", readInt(NUMBER));
    }
}

   public void setTotal(int total) {
    writeInt(NUMBER, total);
    setView(R.id.numberView, "", this.total);
   }
   public void setView(int view, String writeBefore, int num) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(view); >> NullPointerException
    textView.setText(writeBefore + Integer.toString(num));
   }

************************************************
                  Second Class 
************************************************    

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dev);
    Main main = new Main();
    total = main.getTotal();
    perClick = main.getPerClick();
    $ = main.get$();
    devListView();
}

final EditText editTotal = new EditText(Dev.this);
            final EditText editPerClick = new EditText(Dev.this);
            final EditText edit$ = new EditText(Dev.this);
            editTotal.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            editPerClick.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            edit$.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Builder devTotal = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dev.this);
                devTotal.setTitle("Set Total").setView(editTotal).setNeutralButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        main.setTotal(Integer.parseInt(editTotal.getText().toString())); ************ Call to Main to SetTotal
                    }
                });
                devTotal.create().show();
                break;
```

Comment: What is that?? IS it a Fragment? Activity?

Comment: add both activity xml also.. u can pass Textview obj directly and u can directly set with that obj instead of findViewById()

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with this code, but most importantly, the approach you are trying to use is just plain wrong. You need to go back through the basics of Android.  There are several ways for one Activity to update another.  Start by reading about `Interace` and `startActivityForResult()`..  You should not treat activities as  POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
Main main = new Main();
```

it looks like your are creating activity (R.layout.activity_main) by calling `new Main()`, you should not do it like that: you start activities with `startActivity`, if you want to send some values to them use `Intent` extras.

Comment: The layout was a little confusing, edits should make it more clear.
The Main instance was to use the getTotal() method and such.
I use startActivity() in Main to start Second, it's just not shown.

Comment: Why are you creating Main activity with new?  This will not allow you to access its widgets.

Comment: How else would I access Main from Second?